# Dynamically pivoting table, but needing non numeral values

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I am trying to use pivoting to alter the result of my query to fit a specific requirement. Here's a short overview of the situation:

*Database Structure*

[image]

*Normal query*

I need to have an overview over which person currently has which status to a specific job.
So naturally, I'd query it using something like this maybe:

```
select 
p.firstname,
pjl.status
from tbl_person p 
inner join tbl_person_job_link on pjl.ref_person = p.id
inner join tbl_job j on pjl.ref_job = j.id
where j.id = <some id>
```

Naturally, I'd get a result like this maybe:

| firstname | status |
| --- | --- |
| Marc | Requested |
| Esmeralda | Accepted |

Fun thing is, I need it in a format, like you'd have it on an appointment planner:

| job_name | Marc | Esmeralda |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JobA | Requested | Accepted |

I figured that pivoting could be the solution to given requirement, but I am not entirely sure though. As far as I am aware, pivoting is using numeral values, which I do not need in this case. So... is it actually possible?

Here's what I have so far. Also, the thing has to be dynamic because of relations:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(firstname) 
                from tbl_person
                group by firstname
                order by firstname
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT * 
          from 
          (
            select 
            j.job_name, 
            jl.status
            from tbl_person p inner join tbl_person_job_link jl on jl.ref_person = p.id inner join tbl_job j on j.id = jl.ref_job
          ) x
          pivot 
          (
            max(Status)
            for Status in (' + @cols + ')
          ) p '
execute(@query)
```

Which works to some extent as I want it to:

[image]

But I still need the "status" to be shown as value. Since it is technically possible to have multiple links from the same person to the same job, the status should be string_agg'd.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @GarethD 2019E, but the production server is still on 2014E, so let's go with that one

Comment: for firstname in ('+@cols+') , you want the max status for the names. So the FOR part of the pivot which is being compared to the names list, needs to be the name column used to build the names list. The obvious problem with this is the assumption you have only 1 person per first name, and that if they have multiple entries you are wanting the last alphabetically sorted status.